# Fiori theme launchpad and controls are not working properly. Even the radio button in applications look different

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

[image: Fiori launchpad image]

[image: Application- Radio buttons look different]

Above images or fiori launchpad or controls are working properly for all other users except for one. As you can see, highlighted red one is the icon and in the 2nd image radio buttons are looking different. Not able to understand, if any role or authorization is missing.

Comment: Caching problem? Can the users clear their browser cache? Can you check the network tab if some resources couldn't get loaded? Are there console errors? What browser is the user using?

Comment: I have cleared the cache. We are using same browser version but in my case it is working but for other user is not working and in network tab there are no errors

Comment: Have you upgrade the UI5 version recently? The theme could be broken and you might need to regenerate it using Theme Designer (transaction /UI5/THEME_DESIGNER)

Comment: Different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

UI Theme designer with version lower than 1.63 has some issues with fonts while generating  themes for SapUI5/OpenUI5 version above 1.8x: check if in your Developer Tools console there are errors regarding .woff2 files.

It is a known problem as stated in [this post](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13172895/ui5-theme-designer-failed-to-decode-downloaded-fon.html) : the UI Theme Designer Team implemented a specific fix for this starting from version 1.63.